# xmlrequest does not return text from php

Tags: javascript, php, html, xmlhttprequest

I need to find some tools to be able to call .php from .html.
Here is a problem:
while this example works, from .php file:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8">

    </head>
    <body>

    <p>Your IP is </p>
    <?php
            echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    ?>
    <hr />
    </body>
</html>
```

this example doesn't echoes IP in .html file:

> ---from index.html---

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function getIpNumber() {
            var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                    document.getElementById("showIpNumber").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("POST","getip.php",true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }    

        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="getIpNumber();">  
    <p>Your IP is <span id="showIpNumber"></span></p>
</html>
```

> ---from getip.php---

```
<?php
    echo "$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']";
?>
```

what is wrong here?

Comment: Look at your browser's developer tools. Look at the JavaScript console. Does it report any errors? Look at the Net tab. Is the request being made? Does it get a response? Do they contain the data you expect?

Comment: @Quentin, indeed, there was an error 500, but i've found what was wrong

Comment: [**As posted below**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26034671/1415724) @YaroslavAlexeevich it was the double quotes encapsulating `"$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']"` - details are in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line

```
echo "$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']";
```

to

```
echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

having error reporting on would have signaled:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /file.php on line 2

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help during production testing.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

---

As pointed out by Knossos in a comment:

*"You can also use `echo "{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}";` Although in this case, that would be quite pointless. It can be useful in bigger more complicated strings though."*

Comment: thanks, @Fred, though, seems strange why double quotes are not interpreting $

Comment: You can also use echo "{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}"; Although in this case, that would be quite pointless. It can be useful in bigger more complicated strings though.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this line

```
echo "$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']";
```

to this

```
echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```